# Finding the maximum sum of elements of a given array

Tags: python

I have to find the maximum sum of elements in an array (or their permuted form), value of elements depends upon their position in the array

An algorithm for finding sum of the particular array is as follows

```
int taste = 0
for (int i= 0; i <= N; i++){
    if (p[i]) - p[i-1]) >= 0):
        taste += i * (p[i]) - p[i - 1])
    else:
        taste += i * (p[i - 1] - p[i])
```

My solution was is in python but i am always getting result as 0

```
from itertools import permutations
def sum_permuatations ():
    t = int(input())
    taste = 0
    maxTaste = 0
    while ( t!=0):
        t = t-1
        lent = input()
        lis = input()

        for p in permutations(lis, len(lent)):
            for i in range(2,len(p)+1):
                if (int(p[i]) - int(p[i-1]) >= 0):
                    taste += i*(int(p[i])-int(p[i-1]))
                else:
                    taste += i*(int(p[i-1])- int(p[i]))
            if taste > maxTaste:
                maxTaste = taste
        return maxTaste
```

please help me resolving the error in my code.

Comment: `=+` does not do what you think it does. it should be `+=` .

Comment: why are you using a while loop and just returning after one loop?

Comment: I think issue is with indentation. Last return must be de-indented by one step So, that must not be part of while loop.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "the maximum sum of elements in an array (or their permuted form), value of elements depends upon their position in the array".

Comment: @  Padraic Cunningham, this was asked in programming interview,  input was as follows 1st line : no. of test cases   2nd line :len of array 3rd line : elements of array

Comment: if taste > maxTaste:  "taste" will always contain the final iteration through the for() loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution also uses the `itertools` library to generate the various permutations. For each of those the max adjacent sum formula could then be calculated by using `zip` to give consecutive pairs of numbers in the list. The `enumerate` function is used to also give the position of each pair.

```
import itertools

input_list = [10, 15, 16]
result = []

for perm in itertools.permutations(input_list):
    sum_diff = 0
    for i,pair in enumerate(itertools.izip(perm[:-1], perm[1:])):
        sum_diff += abs(pair[0]-pair[1]) * (i+2)
    result.append((sum_diff, perm))

result.sort()
print result[-1]
```

Which would give the following result:

```
(28, (15, 10, 16))
```

Or if you print the whole list:

```
[(13, (10, 15, 16)), (15, (10, 16, 15)), (17, (16, 15, 10)), (20, (15, 16, 10)), (27, (16, 10, 15)), (28, (15, 10, 16))]
```

Your solution has a couple of minor issues, using `range` will start with 0. Also `taste` needs to be zeroed for each permutation as follows:

```
from itertools import permutations

def sum_permuatations(lis):
    maxTaste = 0

    for p in permutations(lis):
        taste = 0
        for i in range(1,len(p)):
            if (int(p[i]) - int(p[i-1]) >= 0):
                taste += (i+1)*(int(p[i]) - int(p[i-1]))
            else:
                taste += (i+1)*(int(p[i-1]) - int(p[i]))

        if taste > maxTaste:
            maxTaste = taste

    return maxTaste

input_list = [10, 15, 16]
print sum_permuatations(input_list)
```

You will need to edit it back to prompt for the input, this just made it easier to test. You could edit it to also use the `abs` command to avoid needing to do this subtraction in the different order.

Comment: `permutations(input_list, len(input_list))` ==> simply `permutations(input_list)`